# Кнопка перестает работать когда добавляю блюр

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь сделать фон на кнопке с блюр эффектом, но когда добавляю блюр, кнопка перестает работать (при нажатии ничего не происходит)

```
extension UIView {
  func addBlurBackground(withAnimator animator: UIViewPropertyAnimator, blurIndicator: CGFloat) {
    let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: nil)
    visualEffectView.frame = self.bounds
    visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    
    self.addSubview(visualEffectView)
    animator.addAnimations {
      visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    }
      
    animator.fractionComplete = CGFloat(blurIndicator)
  }
}


let animatorForSignIn = UIViewPropertyAnimator()
  
func setButtonStyle() {
  signIn_button.addBlurBackground(withAnimator: animatorForJoinUs, blurIndicator: 0.5)
}
```

Почему не работает и как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте строчку:

```
visualEffectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```